# how to retrieve the location/area from given coordinates?

Tags: r, reverse-geocoding

I have columns in my data frame for longitude and latitude, which has specific coordinates such as:

```
longitude      latitude
-80.21148009   26.05230418
-96.70594765   40.82043599
...
```

How can I map the coordinate data I have with the corresponding city/region/state?

Ideally, this would be flexible; for example, I could map to the state-level if needed, or by zip code for another application.

I know there are some packages that can map cities to coordinates, but I haven't been able to find a method that can link coordinates to over-arching regions.

Comment: Are your coordinates all in the USA (as the examples are), or are they also global?

Comment: this is called "reverse geocoding": start with https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+geocoding+R

Comment: there's even a [reverse-geocoding] tag on SO, so try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+reverse-geocoding

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called reverse geocoding. There are multiple packages that will get you there. For example, you can use `ggmap::revgeocode` based off Google Geocoding and Places API. It needs your Google credentials to work:

```
ggmap::revgeocode(c(-80.21148009, 26.05230418))
```

See `?ggmap::revgeocode` for details.